# SQL to LINQ with JOIN and SubQuery

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql

I have a query that I' struggling to convert to LINQ. I just can't get my head around the required nesting. Here's the query in SQL (just freehand typed):

```
SELECT V.* FROM V 
INNER JOIN VE ON V.ID = VE.V_ID
WHERE VE.USER_ID != @USER_ID
  AND V.MAX > (SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM VE 
  WHERE VE.V_ID = V.ID AND VE.STATUS = 'SELECTED')
```

The Closest I've come to is this:

```
var query = from vac in _database.Vacancies
                        join e in _database.VacancyEngagements
                            on vac.Id equals e.VacancyId  into va
                        from v in va.DefaultIfEmpty()
                        where vac.MaxRecruiters > (from ve in _database.VacancyEngagements
                                                     where ve.VacancyId == v.Id && ve.Status == Enums.VacanyEngagementStatus.ENGAGED
                                                     select ve).Count()
```

...which correctly resolves the subquery from my SQL statement. But I want to further restrict the returned V rows to only those where the current user does not have a related VE row.

Comment: You can put `where e.UserId != userId` right before the `into` keyword.

Comment: @GertArnold, that results in a syntax error: "a query body must end with a select clause or a group clause"

Comment: Your query was already missing a `select` at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've realised that the SQL in the question was misleading and whilst it led to technically correct answers, they weren't what I was after. That's my fault for not reviewing the SQL properly so I apologise to @Andy B and @Ivan Stoev for the misleading post. Here's the LINQ that solved the problem for me. As stated in the post I needed to show vacancy rows where no linked vacancyEngagement rows existed. The ! operator provides ability to specify this with a subquery.

```
var query = from vac in _database.Vacancies
                            where !_database.VacancyEngagements.Any(ve => (ve.VacancyId == vac.Id && ve.UserId == user.Id))
                            && vac.MaxRecruiters > (from ve in _database.VacancyEngagements
                                                 where ve.VacancyId == vac.Id && ve.Status == Enums.VacanyEngagementStatus.ENGAGED
                                                 select ve).Count()
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
var filterOutUser = <userId you want to filter out>;

var query = from vac in _database.Vacancies
 join e in _database.VacancyEngagements
                            on vac.Id equals e.VacancyId                            
where (e.UserId != filterOutUser) && vac.MaxRecruiters > (from ve in _database.VacancyEngagements
                                                             where ve.VacancyId == vac.Id && ve.Status == Enums.VacanyEngagementStatus.ENGAGED
                                                             select ve).Count()
        select vac;
```

I removed the join to VacancyEngagements but if you need columns from that table you can add it back in.

Comment: Thanks, Andy B. That expression does work, and it was actually where I started. But it doesn't resolve the 2nd part of the question, eliminating V records where the USER_ID has a linked VE record.

Comment: Sorry about that, I'll ammend the answer a bit later

Comment: Hi Andy. Like another answer here this query returns zero results if the VacancyEngagements table is empty. What I need is for it to return the rows in Vacancies excluding those where a linked (v.Id equals ve.VacancyId) VacancyEngagement row exists for the given user (ve.UserId)